# Is being "not sufficiently useful to the public" a reason to vote for closure?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Suppose someone asks a question duly and properly - shows some effort, provides an MRE or equivalent, is clear and everything. The question even gets an answer, that gets accepted.

However, the scenario is completely trivial, e.g. the resolution is something like "Why would your program print the output you want if you don't issue any printing commands?" or "The problem with your program is exactly what the compiler tells you the error is" etc. Perhaps this should also include, as commenters suggest, solutions which are specific to the individual poster and highly unlikely to be relevant to other users.

Is it acceptable/advisable to vote to close such a question as not being sufficiently useful to the public to keep?

Comment: For typos, a dedicated close reason already exists. There’s also the term “mental typo”. Your title is reminiscent of the old “too localized” reason. But in general, “not sufficiently useful to the public” sounds like “not useful”, which is a downvote reason, not a close reason.

Comment: The "typo" reason also includes posts which were solved in a way unlikely to help future readers, and so may still be valid if not an actual typo

Comment: It's generally frowned upon to provide an answer to a question that contains a typographical error. As mentioned, there is a specific close vote for them. The best thing to do, when you encounter such questions, is to post a comment telling the OP of their typographical error, and then VTC the question as a such. If someone *does* answer they can actually attract downvotes, and I don't specifically disagree with those that do; an answer that says that `Parametr` should be `Parameter`, or the `=` should be a `!=` isn't exactly useful to anyone.

Comment: @yivi Please reopen this question. The example used is about a typo, but the title and the rest of the content ask something completely different, namely the lower limit on the number of people that should be helped by each question.

Comment: Without further clarification from the OP, I feel the dupe is appropriate, @user.

Comment: If it were simply not useful, rather than an actual typo, nearly every debugging question would be eligible for that close reason. Please use your downvotes.

Comment: @yivi: Have I clarified sufficiently?

Comment: Typos are not really relevant to the question as currently phrased, so I removed those dupe targets. However, this is still a dupe of the 'resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers' canonical.

Answer (score -18):

> Is being "not sufficiently useful to the public" a reason to vote for closure?

No, not being useful to a large enough audience is not a reason to close a question. DB storage space is cheap, and search engines are generally good at locating the right question for the right person, so there is no real cost in having a question with a good answer, even if that answer ultimately 'only' helps 10 or 15 people. Arguably even if only 1 person is helped, as long as nobody else is distracted by a question that doesn't help them, that is a net positive for the community.

However, typo questions are different, in the sense that *nobody* learns anything new by reading the answer to such a question. In your example, even the OP of the question isn't less likely to forget the print statement again in a future situation, just because it was mentioned in a previous answer.

So the real criterion shouldn't be how many people are potentially helped, but if **anybody** learned anything new from the answer.

Comment: I'd like to hear from the people that disagree with this answer what is the threshold in terms of number of people helped, that classifies an answer as *useless*, and how they justify this.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I would suggest that you have the reasons in the comments to the question. 8 people, for example, have upvoted [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411245/is-being-not-sufficiently-useful-to-the-public-a-reason-to-vote-for-closure#comment865204_411245), which provides an opinion that is the complete opposite of your answer here. If you include the commenter, and the voters, then maybe half of them have downvoted this.

Comment: No I'm sorry I can't agree. You open the door to ALL questions being valid questions if you lower the bar this far. There may be enough disk space for it all, but definitely not enough curation space. This is Stack Overflow, used by millions of people. It is absolutely not unreasonable to think that a question in a niche tag will help hundreds of people and the average question to help thousands. Over time, of course.

Comment: Fixing typos and trivial mistakes is a waste of everyone's time and should be discouraged. Asking for a specific numerical cutoff isn't relevant. This site should be about interesting programming problems that involve some level of critical thought or insight, not missing semicolons and ilk. Those problems should be solved by programmers on their own.

Comment: @ggorlen something not being eligible for a close reason doesn't make it a good question that we want here. Downvotes are still the most effective way of having posts removed from the network.

Comment: @ggorlen: I agree with you, as I said, typo answers are generally not useful to anyone (a comment should be good enough for OP). My point was it's not the number of people that matters, sometimes questions can be about something so contrived or niche that the number will be small, but they are still helpful.

Comment: @Gimby: Maybe I didn't word it the best way, obviously (as mentioned by OP) the question would need to be on-topic, answerable, not unclear, not a typo, not a duplicate, etc. My objection is only in trying to  forecast the number of people to be helped a priori. Even if few people are helped you are still adding value.

Comment: Helping one person is adding value for one person, not the network.

Comment: "a large enough audience" - what if you believe the question and answer are only useful to an audience of 1 (and another 1 in a billion who will have the exact same circumstances, program, and error, i.e. winning-the-lottery type odds)? PS - not downvoting.

Comment: @einpoklum: If I am *really* convinced that it will only help the OP, and nobody else, I'd probably give the solution in a comment, rather than answering. But that's not that easy to determine beforehand, except in the case of true typos (e.g. idnex instead of index). We have a close reason for them. How many people are helped also depends on how much explanation is in the answer, and how generally it is written, for instance the process to find out what the problem in OP's code was.

Comment: Questions where the OP doesn't understand what the problem is (such as typos) tend to be not useful to future readers, because even if someone does have the same problem, they won't be able to find the question.

Comment: @khelwood: I agree for typos, but I'd argue that if OP fully understood the problem, he would have the answer, and wouldn't need to ask on SO.

Comment: @user000001 I mean that there is a class of questions, including typos, where the person having the problem does not know enough about what is going on to be able to find a suitable question even if it were on the site.

Comment: @user000001 You contradict yourself as long as your post states "Arguably even if only 1 person is helped" - that is the hallmark of an off-topic question. A very selfish, self-serving off-topic question. As I said - you lower the bar too far.